# Run osrm-extract error

Tags: extract, osrm

when run osrm-extract I have this error:

**error while loading shared libraries: libboost_fylesystem.so.1.54.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory**

Answer (score 0):

it is hard to help without details about OS and how OSRM was installed. If it is still an issue please open a ticket at https://github.com/Project-OSRM/osrm-backend/issues